# Batch rename Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, rename, batch-rename

How do you batch rename lots of chrome bookmarks? For example,

1.　"Introduction" is replaced with "Intro"?

2.　"Google" is replaced with "G"?

Comment: I would also like to see this done Via Batch I do know of a freeware tool to help you though if no one can figure out the .bat way http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45646/bulk-rename-tool-is-a-lightweight-but-powerful-renaming-tool/

Comment: I was doing a little more Research and this would actually do what you want it to do if you followed these instructions and installed cygwin http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/shellscripting/batch_rename

Comment: The bookmarks are stolen in a text file under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks` for Windows, and `$HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks` on most linux distros.  The problem is that the file has a checksum field, probably for sync purposes.

Answer (score 9):

1. Export bookmarks (Bookmarks->Bookmarks Manager->Click column in
   upper righthand side that has 3 vertical dots->Export Bookmarks)
2. Make a backup of the bookmarks file incase you mess up
3. Open the file with a text editor
4. Do a find and replace (using regex or just plain text search) to replace whatever you want
5. Import the bookmarks (Bookmarks->Bookmarks Manager->Click column in
   upper righthand side that has 3 vertical dots->Import Bookmarks)

**Note:** This will create a bookmark folder 'Imported'. You will want to replace whatever folders you changed with the folders in the 'Imported' folder. You can also do this through bookmark manager.

There are many ways to create a process/script that will automatically do this on multiple computers if that is your intent. However I read your intent as wanting to update information in multiple bookmarks on one computer, and this will suffice for that purpose.